# GDI+ FillPolygon includes the left and top outline?

Tags: winapi, gdi+

I had a trapezoid created using GDI+ `FillPolygon()`function but found it was 1 pixel off on the right and bottom.  I presumed you passed in the points of the area to fill but reading more closely it says that it fills the inside of the polygon which would make since if it did that.   What I actually found is that the fill function is including the left and top (x,y) but not the right and bottom (x,y).  To make it simple, talking in terms of a rectangle, when filling (0,0)-(10,10), the fill area is (0,0)-(9,9).  I would expect it to either be (0,0)-(10,10) or (1,1)-(9,9).  After all, the points given are all x,y.  So my question is, is that the design? why not documented? or am I missing something?

TIA!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your problem, please see the screenshot below:

[image]

Code:

```
Graphics graphics(hdc);
SolidBrush solidBrush(Color(255, 255, 0, 0));           
Point point1 = Point(0, 0);
Point point2 = Point(0, 10);
Point point3 = Point(10, 10);
Point point4 = Point(10, 0);
Point points[4] = {point1,point2,point3,point4};
graphics.FillPolygon(&solidBrush, points, 4);
```

If there is any difference with your code, please add your code and screenshot in the question.

**Updated:**

I add a new screensnap to research this question:

[image: 2]

**The width/height should be 9 if area inside 0 / 10 (1-9), or 11 if included the x,y points given 0 / 10 (0-10).**

No, the width and height should be 10 pixels. If you mean `DrawRectangle`, the area should be 9x9 pixels excluding 1 pixel pen.

If you use `Rectangle`, the area should be 8x8 pixels excluding 1 pixel pen.

Test code:

```
      Pen blackPen(Color(255, 0, 0, 0), 1);  //1 pixel
      g->DrawRectangle(&blackPen, 0, 24, 10, 10); //10x10

      Rectangle(hdc, 0, 36, 10, 46);  // 10x10

      RECT rect;
      rect.left = 0;            
      rect.top = 12;
      rect.right = 10;
      rect.bottom = 22;
      FillRect(hdc, &rect, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 3)); //10x10
```

Comment: The width/height should be 9 if area inside 0 / 10 (1-9), or 11 if included the x,y points given  0 / 10 (0-10).  Because dealing with x,y (I know the RECT and some of the GDI items do the off by one thing, but other tests I've done with GDI+ didn't have it (because it dealt with x,y, width, height, but seems the fills do with all x,y)? I guess just a Windows graphic API thing for both GDI and GDI+.  thanks.

Comment: the pictures help.  The semantics of the way MS/Windows does it and other graphic and character based frameworks work in other environments (say DOS), are different when it comes to the ending point (bottom right), dealing with X,Y.  In those X,Y in lower right is the ending point (pixel at X,Y is filled and ends there).  Many rect style in Windows it ends at X-1, Y-1 (I'm sure speed as main reason done at first so width/height calculates faster than having to adjust 1).

Answer (score 1):

At least for rectangles this is documented behavior at (Drawing Rectangles)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/drawing-rectangles]. This behavior is similar to how lines work (drawn with LineTo) where the source point is included but the destination excluded. I do not know if the change documented with SetWorldTransform changes how individual lines are drawn.